# static variable data getting modified after new object is created

Tags: c#, static, static-variables

I have created a static variable, and trying to access its content, after creating multiple objects and I am not getting the same value.

```
class Emp
{
    int id;
    static int empID;

    public Emp()
    { 
        empID = id++;        
    }
    public static int geID()
    {
        return empID;
    }

    public static void setEmpID(int value)
    {
        empID = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Emp.setEmpID(76);
        Emp e1 = new Emp();
        Emp e2 = new Emp();
        Console.WriteLine(Emp.geID());
        return 0;        
    }
}
```

Why I am getting '0' at console, whereas I am expecting 76 to be at console.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In constructor you set empID to id (id=0) and AFTER add 1 to id.
I guess you need to change your code like:

```
class Emp
{
    int id;
    static int empID;

    public Emp()
    { 
        id = empID++;
    }
    public static int geID()
    {
        return empID;
    }

    public static void setEmpID(int value)
    {
        empID = value;
    }
}
```